# PHP exec function not working

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to execute a command from php script using php exe function.
The script calls .exe file located in program files whereas my xampp is intalled in E:
I m trying the following command `C:\\Program Files\\GPStill\\pstill.exe` its not working.But if i manually open cmd prompt and stand in c:\prgram files folder than run pstill.exe it works...

Any ideas ???

Comment: Copy and try to exec the script at C:\\pstill.exe - there might be a problem with spacing on windows. If this doesn't help, then look for how to enable exec under windows environment (xampp).

Comment: @Veseliq its enabled but i still added `disable_functions=""
` in the bin/php.ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape the folders for example

```
<?php
$command 'C:\"Program Files"\"Internet Explorer"\iexplore.exe';
exec($command);
?>
```